# Threading and webbrowser control

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, webbrowser-control

I'm very new to threading. I start a thread like this:

```
Thread t_main;
t_main = new Thread(main_building_stuff);
t_main.Start();
```

And at some point, I want in the main_building_stuff to grap some data from an webpage that is loaded into an webbrowser controll in the main thread.

I'm doing that with this piece of code:

```
HtmlElement lit = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("buildqueue");
```

But that results in an error...
InvalidCastException (specified cast is not valid)

What is the proper way to receive the data from the webbrowser?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to scrape data? You might want to take a look over here: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ - The webbrowser isn't a very efficient way to go about it.

Comment: @KingCronus, sounds great, but i want to let the user able to interact with the website (like the controll, the see the site, can click stuff (log in on stuff) and at sertain point, i want to scrap data. Can that be done with the htmlagilitypack?

Comment: "But that results in an error..." - in what error exactly?

Comment: @Spontifixus, question updated.

Comment: Thanks - that very much looks like the Result of GetElementById is no HtmlElement - can you debug to that step and tell us of which type the result of that operation is?

Comment: So post that answer as answer to this question and mark it as answered :)

Comment: it is a bug in the HtmlDocument class.  You can work around it by using the ActiveXInstance property.  But that's not easier than marshaling the call yourself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that to me @HansPassant, but the answer below is good and it works. But thanks anyway

Comment: @TWCrap mark your answer as Answer - by clicking the checkmark icon below the answer score, so others can see that this question has been answered

Comment: i know, and i will, but i have to wait 2 days, because i answerd myself....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somebody that answerd the question, gave the right answer. But for some reason, he deleted it, so thank you, but i don't remember your name...

This was the piece of code that worked:

```
webBrowser1.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                    HtmlElement lit = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("buildqueue");
                    result = "whatever";
                }));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.

`System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument.GetElementById()` definitely returns a `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement`.

What happens if you change

```
HtmlElement lit = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("buildqueue");
```

to

```
System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement lit = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("buildqueue");
```

Do you still get an invalid cast error?

I just happen to know that there are multiple commonly used classes called `HtmlElement` and I wonder if you've got one from another namespace imported.

Comment: The problem was that i ran it from an other thread. So i couldn't acces the webbrowser...

Comment: That wouldn't have caused an `InvalidCastException`, but nevertheless I'm glad your problem is fixed.

Comment: well, if you say so, but somehow, i only added that, and it works... But thanks for thinking with the others for tryibg to fix the problem